# HTML Canvas | Grab rows of data from an array using X/Y coordinates and a view-port width/height

Tags: javascript, canvas

Let's say I have a array of numbers denoting a tilemap (64x64) and a player x,y coordinate. I also have a viewport (in tiles). Using those, I can create a 5x5 tilemap (viewport) with a player x,y and draw it like so:

https://codesandbox.io/s/map-loader-only-viewport-6jhric?file=/src/index.js

The problem I am running into is that when I grab the `layer[]` array... I have to comb through the whole arrayset.

Could I just not grab the tiles needed and send over 25 array (5x5) elements instead of the whole map (400 array elements)

Comment: I'm afraid your question ain't too clear. What exactly is your problem? You don't want to download the complete .png image upfront?

Comment: @obscure I am trying to get an array of 25 elements based on the player x/y and viewport. So instead of passing 400 elements.. I just get 25 elements.

Comment: Sorry - I still do not understand what your problem is. Where does this array come from since you're worried about sending it in it's entirety? From a server and you only want to request the 25 tiles that make up the current viewport?

Comment: @obscure Correct. The array would be stored on a Node.js server and a browser (client) would be trying to access it. But it would just pull the 25 array elements instead of the 400 to send through.